# How to join two not too related tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really having difficulty doing a join? How can i join two table that the only relation is the username. For example:

I have two tables. tableone and tabletwo each with there own respective rows and columns.

Table One

```
id    trans_ref     username    amount
2      12345        peter         50
3       45678       john          30
4       8790        frank         10
```

Table Two

```
id     trans_ref     username     recurring     status     company     date_order      amt
1     78987           peter       weekly        paid       new lad      12/10/2015      30
2     88776           john        monthly       unpaid     green        15/05/2015      10
3     55667           frank       yearly        paid       blue         17/05/2015      25
```

how do i perform a join so that all the values will be avail to me

```
$stm = $pdo->....
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['status']; //etc
}
```

Comment: the same way you join anything else. `on t1.username = t2.username`. hopefully username is unique.

Comment: Why does Table 1 and Table 2 include column "username".  Normalize your database schema, and move users to a different table.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try normalization. But how can i do that in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both tables have a `trans_ref` column, you'll need to give at least one of them an alias so you can access it distinctly from the other.

```
SELECT t1.trans_ref AS t1_trans_ref, t1.amount, t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.username = t2.username
```

`$row['trans_ref']` will be the `trans_ref` column from `table2`, `$row['t1_trans_ref']` will be the `trans_ref` column from `table1`.

Comment: Thanks. But the result is replicated and also i was hoping to a null where there is no match in the column.

Comment: If you want rows with no match, use `LEFT JOIN`. I'm not sure what you mean by the result being replicated. If there are multiple matches, it will join them all to create a cross-product, that's how joins work. If you want something different, please update the question with the desired output.